# Prevent Dialog from closing after pressing OK - SPFX Extension Listview Command

Tags: spfx, listviewcommandset

I created a spfx extension that shows a dialog using

```
 Dialog.alert(`Are you sure you want to open Quarter ${selectedItem.Quarter} for Period ${selectedItem.Period}?`).then(() => {
      this.updateSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    });
```

then updates selected item if the user press Ok.
Its working but, even if i dont click OK and just click outside the dialog, it will still update the selected item.

How can i add cancel button?

Also i want to display a spinner inside the dialog when the user press OK. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing `Dialog.alert(message).then(/*stuff*/)`, you are saying that you want `Dialog` to `alert`, then *always* run the `/*stuff*/` after the dialog closes, regardless of the way it closes. This leads to the behavior you observe.

To your first question, I would hazard a guess that there's a similar method `Dialog.confirm(message).then(/*stuff*/)`, which would prompt the user for a "OK" or "Cancel" response, then runs `/*stuff*/` conditionally only if the user selected "OK". However, I'm not sure what Dialog API you're using, so I recommend you review the documentation for that component/library for details.

In the worst case, you could create an event listener on the OK button which sets a boolean (ex. `userClickedOk`) to `true` when the user clicks OK, so the code could look like this:

```
Dialog.alert(`Are you sure you want to...?`).then(() => {
    if (userClickedOk) {
        this.updateSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    }
});
```

To your second question, you'll need to provide more details about the library you're using. It's certainly possible - with vanilla JavaScript, you could attach an event listener to the "OK" button, which then attaches some spinner HTML to the dialog. But there might be a better/easier way provided through the API.

Comment: Are you using the Dialog from `@microsoft/sp-dialog`? If so, it looks like they do not have a simple Yes/No or Ok/Cancel dialog type. However they give you an implementable class called `[BaseDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-dialog/basedialog?view=sp-typescript-latest)` which you can use to create your own Dialog with the specific requirements. You can see [Use custom dialog boxes with SPFx Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx) which addresses List View Command Sets.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I already solved the problem by creating a custom dialog